# Перевод результата запроса в массив строк

Tags: postgresql, синтаксис, c++

Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом перегнать результаты выполнения хранимой процедуры на postgresql, да и вообще каков синтаксис вызова хранимой процедуры базы postgresql на с++, которая читает пути (к директориям или файлам) из некотрой таблицы базы в массив строк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Библиотека называется libpq. Вот как с ней работать

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <postgresql/libpq-fe.h>
#include <string>

int     main() {
    PGconn          *conn;
    PGresult        *res;
    int             rec_count;
    int             row;
    int             col;

    conn = PQconnectdb("dbname=ljdata host=localhost user=dataman password=supersecret");
    if (PQstatus(conn) == CONNECTION_BAD) {
        puts("Не удается подключиться к базе данных");
        exit(0);
    }

    res = PQexec(conn, "select lastname,firstname,phonenumber from people order by id");

    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK) {
        puts("Мы не получили данные");
        exit(0);
    }

    rec_count = PQntuples(res);

    printf("Мы получили %d записей.\n", rec_count);
    puts("==========================");

    for (row=0; row<rec_count; row++) {
        for (col=0; col<3; col++) {
            printf("%s\t", PQgetvalue(res, row, col));
        }
        puts("");
    }

    puts("==========================");
    PQclear(res);
    PQfinish(conn);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю, что соответсвенно запись в массив будет осуществляться так:

string array[rec_count];
for (row=0; row<rec_count; row++) {        
for (col=0; col<3; col++) {            
array[rec_count]=PQgetvalue(res, row, col));
        }

Comment: нет, вам нужно хотя бы двумерный массив, одна размерность для полей выбранных из таблицы, а другая для выбранных строк